# Should I pass request object to goroutine in blocking for-select loop coming from channel?

Tags: loops, go, goroutine

I have the following for-select structure in code:

```
go func(runCh chan Caller, shutdownSignal chan bool) {
        for {
            select {
            case request := <-runCh:
                go func() {
                    w.Run(&request)
                }()
            case <-shutdownSignal:
                w.Shutdown()
                return
            }
        }
    }(runCh, shutdownCh)
```

Will I have some problems with this part:

```
case request := <-runCh:
    go func() {
        w.Run(&request)
    }()
```

?

If yes, then why?

**In other words - does [Using goroutines on loop iterator variables part of Common Mistakes](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables) also apply to my case and why it does/does not apply here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No (**does not apply here**), you have new variable (memory address) on each loop iteration:

```
 case request := <-runCh:
```

Because this `:=` creates new variable distinct from previous one, proof:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    runCh := make(chan int, 2)
    runCh <- 1
    runCh <- 2
    for i := 1; i <= 2; i++ {
        select {
        case request := <-runCh:
            go func() {
                fmt.Println(request, &request)
                time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)
                fmt.Println(request, &request)

            }()
        }
    }
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)

}
```

Output (the address of `request` in each loop iteration is different):

```
1 0xc0000b8000
2 0xc0000b8008
1 0xc0000b8000
2 0xc0000b8008
```

See: 0xc0000b8000 != 0xc0000b8008

Comment: This is accurate but somewhat misleading - the `:=` is not what distinguishes it from the issue with using `for` loop variables, even when those are created with `:=`.

Comment: For each goroutine call **here** it will be one and only one new `request` variable here. if you change `:=` to simple `request = <-runCh` then that problem will occur here too. so yes that is all, and then you need to call it like: `go func(request int) { ... }(request)`

Comment: Actually if you change it to `request = <- runCh` it will fail with `request` undefined, but that's not what I was referring to. The `:=` is not what separates this case from the case OP linked to regarding `for` loop iterators, which have the issue regardless of whether you use `:=` or not.

Comment: Of course for `request = <-runCh` you need `var request int`. For the OP's case there is only one reference to `request` which is used inside the only goroutine, so here the OP's case is simple and clear. Your point will be valid if you add another statement that changes `request` value concurrently, which is the linked page refers to. which is another case of course. and out of this QA. so I highlighted the word **here** to show this point. Nice talking to you, have a great time.